# How to change specific keys in the keyboard?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

My Down and Right arrow keys were no longer functioning. Therefore, it is very difficult to use my laptop.So I want to change the key map like this:

- Pg up to function as Up arrow key
- Pg down to function as Down arrow key
- Up arrow key to function as Right arrow key

Best regards,

Phong

Comment: Is this in X, the terminal, somewhere else specific? Please [edit] your post with as much detail as you can.

Comment: I want to change like that everywhere, captain.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) which works only with X.

In a file (for example: `~/.Xmodmap`),  write something like this:

```
keycode 0x63 = Up
keycode 0x69 = Down
```

You just have to execute `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to enable your new configuration.

[Here you will find a list](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Intkeyb/x336.html) of all the `keycode` and to what key they correspond.

Comment: That's really cool. But do you have any idea how to do the same thing in `tty`? BTW, nice name!

Comment: Indeed, this solution uses X. I don't know an alternative if you want to use it without X.

Comment: It did not work bro

Answer (score 1):

A solution for X11 is described in the post by @Jav.  Remapping the keys in the Linux console:

1. read the docs: `man 5 keymaps`
2. dump the current mappings to a file with `dumpkeys`
3. run `showkey` to find the keycodes for the keys you want to remap
4. change the relevant entries in the file produced by `dumpkeys`
5. install the new mappings with `loadkeys`.

Steps 2., 3., and 5. need to be done from the actual Linux console, otherwise you'll get an error message about a file descriptor for the console.

Making the changes permanent probably involve running `loadkeys` at boot, and making sure the normal boot procedure doesn't override your mappings with keyboard locales.